# Tomcat or JBoss for JSF, Hibernate project

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jboss, jsf-2

I am working on academic project, which is supposed to be as small as possible without useless features, covering only its initial requirements, which also are not too broad.
Two main technologies, which I have chosen to work with is JavaServer Faces 2 (probably with CDI) and Hibernate. I don't need anything more.
I need some server to deploy my application on. My first thought was Tomcat, but as far I know it only serves Java Servlets API and JSP.
My question is which of the following solutions are better, easier to develop and less troublemaking in cooperation with my small project?

1. Use Tomcat and try to extend it with JSF and Hibernate libraries
2. Use JBoss Application Server

The reason that I haven't chosen JBoss first is that I have no experience with it at all. Till know, I worked only with Tomcat. I have also wondered if it isn't shooting from cannon to mosquito.
Please help mi with decision.

Comment: Yes, it is the first layered architecture application prepared in Java EE environment. I have been .NET fan so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other constraints, use Tomcat. It's open source and free. JSF works perfectly well with it. I don't know about CDI, but there doesn't seem to be any reason not to use Tomcat.

If, however, you require functionality which is in JBoss (advanced security features for example) but not in Tomcat, then use that.

Personally, I'd just go for the simple solution (i.e Tomcat) and only if necessary switch to JBoss. If you write code for Tomcat, in general it will work with JBoss, but not necessarily the other way around, because JBoss has more functionality.

Comment: Do you think it's a good thing for a novice to start with administering Tomcat instead of working with a complete JavaEE container? there are a couple of obstacles that could prevent him from doing his work, like this one http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1937

Comment: 1) You don't know the OP is a novice. 2) He said in the question 'Till now, I worked only with Tomcat'.

Comment: JBoss has more functionality, but they force their jars into your app (before JBoss 7 anyway).  I like tomcat better because you can specify the jars you want without class loading issues.  Pre-7-JBoss always gave me problems getting JSF to work.  Tomcat+Maven+Any jars you need is easier to me.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell from comment now we know that OP is a novice ;)

Answer (score 1):

IMO NetBeans + Glassfish combination is more suitable for beginners b/c of tight integration and stability.

Oracle is targeting this combination specifically for educational purposes to promote JavaEE, so there are lots of tutorials and samples that work right away.

If using EclipseLink instead of Hibernate would be OK for your project, of course...